# Why don't seconds convert (strptime/strftime)?

Tags: ruby, datetime

I am trying to convert to Mysql time datetime format but the seconds do not convert, only the date looks fine.

```
1.9.3-p448 :030 >  d = Date.strptime "26 Jul 2013 00:04:52 UTC", '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'
=> #<Date: 2013-07-26 ((2456500j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
1.9.3-p448 :031 > d.strftime ("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
=> "2013-07-26 00:00:00"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a `Date`, which has no time. Try using a `DateTime`:

```
irb [1.9.3]$ require "date"
=> true
irb [1.9.3]$ d = DateTime.strptime "26 Jul 2013 00:04:52 UTC", '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S'
=> #<DateTime: 2013-07-26T00:04:52+00:00 ((2456500j,292s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
irb [1.9.3]$  d.strftime ("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
=> "2013-07-26 00:04:52"
```

Answer (score 2):

You must use a [Time class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Time.html) insted of [Date](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html). Cause `Date` holds only a date like `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Example:

```
root@ubuntu-server:~# irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'time'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> t = Time.parse("26 Jul 2013 00:04:52 UTC")
=> Fri Jul 26 00:04:52 UTC 2013
irb(main):003:0> t.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
=> "2013-07-26 00:04:52"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong type use `DateTime`

```
1.9.3-p448 :030 >  d = DateTime.strptime "26 Jul 2013 00:04:52 UTC", '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'
=> #<DateTime: 53060389273/21600,0,2299161>
1.9.3-p448 :031 > d.strftime ("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
=> "2013-07-26 00:04:52"
```